# ASP.Net MVC 6 Optimization with Threads

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc, performance, optimization, threadpool

Looking for advice on using Thread.

I have controller, which do query in DB and transform selected data in List. But in some case i need extra information for several rows. I don't want new query in loop for each rows.
If i will start new Thread, which will do extra query as parallel with my main loop and add extra information to List. It's good or not. Or better get all data before.
is it worth running additional threads for the sake of subrequests, or is it better to add them through?

Sample:

```
    [HttpPost]
      public async Task<IActionResult> ReestrRazr(DateTime date)
      {
        List<SomeClass> arr = new List<SomeClass>();
 string query = " SELECT [table].[id], [table].[snumber], [table].[datein], [table].[datefileeate], [table].[istatusU], [table].[datezamechania], [table].[type], [table].[isubtypeU], ";
                query += " [tableT3040].[content] as [address], [tableT3040].[nazvanie] as [objNazvanie], ";
                query += " [tableT101].[nazvanie] as zastrName, ";
                query += " [adress].[rajon], ";
                query += " [objT3].[idcomlinknypredstavitelpurpose] as [nadzor] ";

                query += " FROM ((((((((([table] ";
                query += "  JOIN [link] on (([table].[id]=[link].[idlinkper]) and ([link].[ideletestate]=0)) ) ";
                query += " JOIN [file] on (([file].[id]=[link].[idlink]) and ([file].[sfileextension] like ('%pdf%')) and ([file].[ideletestate]=0)) ) ";
                query += " JOIN [obj] ON ([table].[identity]=[obj].[id] AND [obj].[ideletestate]=0)  ) ";
                query += " LEFT JOIN [objT] as [objT3] on (([objT3].[identity]=[obj].[id]) and ([objT3].[type]=3) and ([objT3].[ideletestate]=0)) )";
                query += " LEFT JOIN [adress]  ON (([obj].[idaddress]=[adress].[id]) and ([adress].[ideletestate]=0) and ([adress].[workstate]=1)) ) ";
                query += " LEFT JOIN [objT] as [objT119] on (([objT119].[identity]=[obj].[id]) and ([objT119].[type]=119) and ([objT119].[ideletestate]=0) and ([objT119].[idcomlinknypredstavitelpurpose] = 1)) )";
                query += " LEFT JOIN [tableT] as [tableT3040] on (([table].[id]=[tableT3040].[idlinkper]) and ([tableT3040].[type]=3040) and ([tableT3040].[ideletestate]=0)) ) ";
                query += " LEFT JOIN [tableT] as [tableT101] on (([table].[id]=[tableT101].[idlinkper]) and ([tableT101].[type]=101) and ([tableT101].[nazvanie] <> '') and ([tableT101].[nazvanie] is not null) and ([tableT101].[ideletestate]=0)) )";
                query += " left join [ae] on (([table].[idcomlinkny]=[ae].[id]) and ([ae].[ideletestate]=0)) ) ";
        DataTable dt = Execute4Table(query + $" where date >'{date.tostring("yyyyMMdd")}'")
        foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
        {
          int id = Convert.ToInteger(row[0]);
          int type = Convert.ToInteger(row[1]);
          string number= Convert.ToString(row[2]);
         
          SomeClass sc = new SomeClass();
          sc.id=id;
          sc.number = number;
    
          if (type==50)
           {
            number = Convert.ToString(ExecuteScalar("select number from table WHERE idparent="+ id.tostring()));
           }
    
          arr.Add(sc);
        }
    }
```

Thx!(sry for my english)
P.S. Real query have 8 JOIN and obtaining all the necessary information will lead to an increase in the number of JOINs to 12-13. This is bad for performance.

Comment: You **absolutely** don't need threads for that. Learn SQL, perhaps a join is all that's needed.

Comment: What are you trying to do in the first place? If you wanted to retrieve related entries from another table, all you'd have to do is a JOIN. IN this case what is `idparent`? Is your *real* question how to perform a hierarchical query? This has been answered already and doesn't require client-side threads.

Comment: Too much join is bad for performance. It's why i'am thinking about other ways.

Answer (score 1):

You won't be able to run parallel queries from the same DbContext (request scoped). I would either do `left outer join` for one query that will bring You all the data You need, nulls for other rows or allow client side to make extra requests for those rows, request/row. Although I would stick to the first idea as long as it won't turn out that those "extras" couse a basic version of the query to slow down drastically. The 3ed option is to just `await` for the main query, gather selected IDs from the in-memory result and do second query with `IN`, dealing with assigning the values later in memory.

Comment: Yeap, I mostly use your third option. But today I decided to think about whether it can be further accelerated. Thank.